# need to find a value with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is a part of HTML code from following page [following page](https://orange.e-sim.org/battle.html?id=5377):

```
<div>
 <div class="sidebar-labeled-information">
  <span>
   Economic skill:
  </span>
  <span>
   10.646
  </span>
 </div>
 <div class="sidebar-labeled-information">
  <span>
   Strength:
  </span>
  <span>
   2336
  </span>
 </div>
 <div class="sidebar-labeled-information">
  <span>
   Location:
  </span>
  <div>
   <a href="region.html?id=454">
    Little Karoo
    <div class="xflagsSmall xflagsSmall-Argentina">
    </div>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="sidebar-labeled-information">
  <span>
   Citizenship:
  </span>
  <div>
   <div class="xflagsSmall xflagsSmall-Poland">
   </div>
   <small>
    <a href="pendingCitizenshipApplications.html">
     change
    </a>
   </small>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to extract `region.html?id=454` from it. I don't know how to narrow the search down to `<a href="region.html?id=454">`, since there are a lot of `<a href=>` tags.

Here is the python code:

```
session=session()
r = session.get('https://orange.e-sim.org/battle.html?id=5377',headers=headers,verify=False) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'sidebar-labeled-information'})
```

And the output of this code is:

```
[<div class="sidebar-labeled-information" id="levelMission">
<span>Level:</span> <span>15</span>
</div>, <div class="sidebar-labeled-information" id="currRankText">
<span>Rank:</span>
<span>Colonel</span>
</div>, <div class="sidebar-labeled-information">
<span>Economic skill:</span>
<span>10.646</span>
</div>, <div class="sidebar-labeled-information">
<span>Strength:</span>
<span>2336</span>
</div>, <div class="sidebar-labeled-information">
<span>Location:</span>
<div>
<a href="region.html?id=454">Little Karoo<div class="xflagsSmall xflagsSmall-Argentina"></div>
</a>
</div>
</div>, <div class="sidebar-labeled-information">
<span>Citizenship:</span>
<div>
<div class="xflagsSmall xflagsSmall-Poland"></div>
<small><a href="pendingCitizenshipApplications.html">change</a>
</small>
</div>
</div>]
```

But my desired output is `region.html?id=454`.

The page which I'm trying to search in is located [here](https://orange.e-sim.org/battle.html?id=5377), but you need to have an account to view the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = soup.findAll('a', href=True)

for link in links:
  href = link['href']
  url = urlparse(href)
  if url.path == "region.html":
     print (url.path + "?" + url.query)
```

This prints `region.html?id=454`

Answer (score 0):

you can try using this class:
`xflagsSmall`
and find the parrent of that element

````
element=soup.find("div",{"class": "xflagsSmall"})
parent_element=element.find_parent()
link=parent_element.attrs["href"]```
````

Comment: hi, ```xflagsSmall-Argentina``` is not a fixed value, it will change in new pages so i cant use it.
solution is to narrow search down to this part:
```<div>
<a href="region.html?id=454">Little Karoo<div class="xflagsSmall xflagsSmall-Argentina"></div>
</a>
</div>
```
then extract the 
```href```
value.

Comment: @Abolfazl broadend the search to match on just xflagsSmall.

Answer (score 0):

You can query on base of href value:

```
element=soup.find("a",{"href": "region.html?id=454"})
element.attrs["href"]
```